# Consultas sobre fechas en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

estoy aprendiendo a usar Entity Framework y estoy realizando una consulta para que me devuelva los datos de una lista, con un rango de fechas y esta me devuelve el total de las fechas que hay en el registro. Aca les dejo la consulta.

```
lstPersonal = _context.Personal.Include(x => x.TipoPersona)
                                           .Include(x => x.IngresosPersonal.OrderBy(x => x.FechaEntrada.Date))
                                           .Where(x => x.IngresosPersonal
                                           .Where(x => x.FechaEntrada.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(fechaDesde).Date && x.FechaEntrada.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(fechaHasta).Date()).Any())
                                           .ToList();
```

Esta es la tabla que consulto que me debería filtrar la FechaEntrada por el rango que le paso.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HUM_IngresosPersonal] (
[IdIngresoPersonal] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[IdPersonal] [int] NOT NULL,
[Tipo] [nchar](50) NULL,
[FechaEntrada] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[FechaSalida] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Observaciones] [nchar](255) NULL,
[IdPersonalCarga] [int] NULL)
```

Comment: Cual esta la relacion entre las tablas TipoPersona y IngresosPersonal

Comment: Y que datos quieres mostrar